# NFC tag reader error message "Feature not supported" in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-nfc

i am developing iOS application in which i am having NFC reading functionality implemented. following is my code.

```
- (IBAction)onClick_btnNFC:(id)sender { 
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
         readerSession = [[NFCNDEFReaderSession alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT) invalidateAfterFirstRead:NO];
  } else {
          [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"NFC Scanner not complitable for current iOS version."];
         }
   readerSession.alertMessage = @"Scan location using NFC Card.";
   [readerSession beginSession];
 }
```

and delegate methods are

```
- (void)readerSession:(nonnull NFCNDEFReaderSession *)session didDetectNDEFs:(nonnull NSArray<NFCNDEFMessage *> *)messages  API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)){

NFCNDEFMessage *lastMessage = messages[0];

NSString *payloadDataString = @"";
NSString *payloadIDString = @"";
NSString *payloadTypeString = @"";

for(NFCNDEFPayload *payload in lastMessage.records){
        
        payloadDataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload.payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        payloadIDString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload.identifier encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSString *payloadTypeString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload.typeNameFormat encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        payloadTypeString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload.type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
}

- (void)readerSession:(nonnull NFCNDEFReaderSession *)session didInvalidateWithError:(nonnull NSError *)error  API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)){

//[readerSession beginSession];
NSLog(@"The session was invalidated: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

if([[error localizedDescription]containsString:@"Feature"]){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:kAppName message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            
        }]];
        
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
  } 
}
```

when i run application in my iPhone 6S which is NFC reading supported as per apple documentation, it always goes in "didInvalidateWithError" method with error message "Feature not supported". i am not sure where i got mistake.

NOTE : I have created provisioning profile with NFC enable and also check NFC capability in my project and also added entitlement file in project as well.

Comment: Could you print `error` instead of `[error localizedDescription]`? And give us the full error message?

Comment: @Larme  Error : Error Domain=NFCError Code=1 "Feature not supported" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Feature not supported}

Comment: @Larme. [CoreNFC] -[NFCHardwareManager queueReaderSession:sessionConfig:completionHandler:]:98  error=Error Domain=NFCError Code=1 "Feature not supported" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Feature not supported}

Comment: While the iPhone 6s has nfc hardware, Core NFC reading is only supported on iPhone 7 and later.

Comment: Shouldn't you test also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcreadersession/3043845-readingavailable first?

Comment: so you mean to say my implementation is perfect but the issue is with my devices ? am i right ?

Comment: @Larme Yes just check and got this in console.
(lldb) po [NFCReaderSession readingAvailable];
NO

Comment: i think you are right @Paulw11 that might be issue with device hardware capability other, will test on higher end device.